# While dragging rectangle object fast, dragging stops

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, drag-and-drop, wpf-controls

While dragging rectangle object fast, dragging stops and cursor only moves. Without releasing button click button, moving the cursor on the rectangle object starts the dragging again. It is dragging fine when i drag on a constant speed.

My code is,

```
    private void ConnectorMethod()
    {
     _draggedLine = new Rectangle();
     _draggedLine.Width = 100;
     _draggedLine.Height = 12;
     _controlModel.PlayerCanvas.Children.Add(_draggedLine);
     _draggedLine.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += copy_Connector;
     _draggedLine.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += connector_leftUp;
    }

    private void copy_Connector(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _connecting_Connector = (Rectangle)sender;
        _Connector_position = e.GetPosition(_connecting_Connector);
        _connecting_Connector.PreviewMouseMove += ConnectorMouseMove;

    }

    private void connector_leftUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _connecting_Connector.PreviewMouseMove -= ConnectorMouseMove;
    }

    private void ConnectorMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            Point canvasRelativePosition = e.GetPosition(_controlModel.PlayerCanvas);
            Canvas.SetTop(_connecting_Connector, canvasRelativePosition.Y - _Connector_position.Y);
            Canvas.SetLeft(_connecting_Connector, canvasRelativePosition.X - _Connector_position.X);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you are dragging fast, do you leave the window then?

Comment: No, With in the window itself dragging stops

Comment: Hmm.... as far as I can tell, you are doing it correctly...

Comment: You should capture the mouse. Try `_connecting_Connector.CaptureMouse();` on mouse down and release it on mouse up by `_connecting_Connector.ReleaseMouseCapture();`

Comment: @Clemens I cannot able to move my rectangle if i use that method.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it with implementation canvas rectangle object in